# GWT DatePicker to show specific day of the Week

Tags: gwt

How do I show only a particular day of the week in gwt-datePicker ?

E.g
If I select January or any month of the year, I want to see only "Tuesdays" for that month.

Cheers
Prince

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: With the default component you cannot.

I would recommend you to create your own widget. Remember that GWT doesn't have support for the Calendar Object, so you'll need to do your own calculations.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have decided to use a validator to validate the date selected (User input) to check the day of the week according to user Input, in my case (Tuesday and Saturday).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement once where the datepicker popup needed to show the week number in an additional column. Since you cannot subclass/override all the necessary behaviour of the standard classes, there was nothing for it in the end but to rip out the source code and create a new implementation with minor changes.
As for date calculations, there is a port of joda time which you can import client-side. Quite a bit of overkill if you only need the day of the week, though.

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-time/